# Where do house search web apps pull their data from?

Tags: statistics

MLS? That's the obvious answer... But why is there differences in the houses that are shown as available on sites like Movoto.com, RedFin.com, and Zillow.com?

Can anyone describe the discrepancy? And which is the most accurate (if there is a non-subjective answer to that)?

Comment: a answer for the UK would also be of interest

Comment: @DoNotInstall - the UK is a totally different ballgame, individual agents pay to have properties listed on one or many "aggregate" sites. Each aggregate site will have listings from a different combination of agents and the method agents use to "upload" a listing will be different for each aggregate site.

Answer (score 0):

If many sites are pulling data from MLS, it is highly possible that they operate different strategies for obtaining the data. For example, they might refresh their listings every hour, or more or less frequently.

Also, they may have criteria for whether a listing is displayed. If a piece of information is missing, they may exclude it from being show.

Another cause for differences may be if they weight their searches in a different way - the result set may contain the same listings, but in a different order.

It's hard to accurately answer the reasons for the differences, but I hope that these pointers are useful.